# Ajax get function array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello stackoverflow community, I need help with ajax `$.get` function. When I recieve array from getlist.php and i alert ir like this `alert(data_list);` everything works correctly. But when I try to alert like this `alert(data_list.id)` it doesn't work. Here is how my array looks like in console:

> [{"id":"2","name":"Something","type":"horizontal","clicks":"0","start_date":"01/20/2016","end_date"
>   :"02/19/2016","status":"1","target":"http://","image_url":"http://","pre_exp_email":"0"},{"id"
>   :"1","name":"None","type":"horizontal","clicks":"2","start_date":"01/20/2016","end_date":"05/19/2016"
>   ,"status":"1","target":"http://wps.us.lt","image_url":"http://....../wp-content/uploads/2016
>   /01/250by250ad.jpg","pre_exp_email":"0","group_id":["1"],"slots":{"1":"1"}}]

And here is myfunction which calls get function.

```
    function get_list() {
        jQuery.get("/wp-content/plugins/wp125/functions/getlist.php", { grouptype:jQuery('#grouptype').val() }, function(data_list){
            var str;
            alert(data_list.name);
        });             
    }
```

Comment: It is an array of objects or just an object??? You need to be more precise in your question. And where do you try to alert: `data_list.id`?

Comment: @A.Wolff array of objects

Comment: So your posted output is quite unrelevant, isn't it?!... And you need to iterate through array to get objects ID.

Comment: If it is array of object then you should do like `data_list[0].name` if more element in array then use `$.each`

Comment: @A.Wolff i updated my array with more then one object. You can look.

Comment: @Sidas you can follow my comment as per your `json`

Comment: @Sidas There are thousand dupes regarding this... All is said anyway... And still not clear what is your expected behaviour. Getting all IDs in an array or getting specific indexed object ID or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is only a object like

```
var k={"id":123;"name":"abc"}
```

you can access id using `k.id`

but when it is object of Array like

```
var k=[{"id":123,"name":"abc"},{"id":13,"name":"ab"}];
```

in that case you have iterate over array something like this

```
for(i=0;i<k.length;i++)
    {console.log(k[i].id)}
```

Comment: I did      for(i=0;i<data_list.length;i++)
         {console.log(data_list[i].id)}
but GET http://wps.us.lt/wp-content/plugins/wp125/functions/getlist.php?grouptype=horizontal
 
200 OK
  347ms 
load-sc...r=4.4.1 (line 5)
486
undefined